# Cannot get gifs with giphy using discord.js, making a bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, giphy, giphy-api

```
if (command === 'fetar') {
    var deadline = new Date("apr 19, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
    var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
    var remainingTime = deadline - currentDate;

    var days = Math.floor(remainingTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
    var hours = Math.floor((remainingTime %(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60)); 
    var minutes = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)); 
    var seconds = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    giphy.search('gifs', {"q": "food"})
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            var totalResponses = response.data.length;
            var responseIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) % totalResponses;
            var responseFinal = response.data[responseIndex];
            message.channel.send(' **E N D   O F   L E N T** ');
            message.channel.send(`**${days}** days, **${hours}** hrs, **${minutes}** mins, **${seconds}** secs`, {
                files: [responseFinal.images.fixed_height.url]})
        })
        .catch (() => {
            console.log('Ya messed up again...')
        })

}
```

Tried to use this code but to no avail, it goes directly to my error catch and does not generate a gif. I tried to console log the steps leading up to this but nothing displayed.

Comment: Can you log the error you get?

Comment: There's no error, I just get the catch that I showed above so the console just says "Ya messed up again..."

Comment: ```.catch ((e) => {
            console.log(e)
        })``` 

I think you can use that

Comment: { status: 403, error: null, statusText: 'Forbidden' }

Comment: as a side note, why do some complicated divisions on the timestamp instead of just using built in proeprties of Date class? ex `hours = new Date().getHours()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are not using an API key, according to [giphy's docs](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/api#response-codes) `403` status means

> You weren't authorized to make your request; most likely this indicates an issue with your API Key.

If you are not using an API key you can get it by following [this guide](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/api/#quick-start-guide)

Comment: I'm using the SDK version as opposed to the regular API version, do you believe this may be the issue?

Comment: Actually I just used the regular API key and it still gave me the same error so I'm quite sure my key is correct and initialized correctly.

Comment: Did you check that the API key is correct? you can check it here: https://developers.giphy.com/dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

I was ridiculous lol, my API key was pulled from a config file but when I was initializing the giphy client I called the key as a string "giphyAPIToken" as opposed to a variable giphyAPIToken lol. Sorry for the trouble fam if you have the same issue and your code is correct check your API key!!!